# Get current timestamp inside query(Spring boot)

Tags: spring-boot, timestamp

How i can get current timestamp inside query?

```
   @Query(value = "SELECT s.* FROM logines.work_hour s WHERE s.start_time between ? and ILIKE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP", nativeQuery = true)
    List<WorkHour> findByStartTime(String startTime);


ERROR: syntax error at or near "CURRENT_TIMESTAMP"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like this

```
 import java.sql.Timestamp;
    @Query(value="SELECT s.* FROM logines.work_hour s WHERE s.start_time 
    between :start and :end",nativeQuery = true)
    User findUser(  
    @Param("start") Timestamp start, 
    @Param("end") Timestamp end);
```

And during function call ,you can pass those parameters.

Getting current timestamp in sql format

```
import java.sql.Timestamp;
Timestamp timestamp = new Timestamp(System.currentTimeMillis());
```

Comment: it needs to be timestamp without timezone

Comment: You can pass java sql timestamp